# Jenkins doesnt build project with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, jenkins

I have an android project whicj was previously built in jenkins successfully. But when I added firebase to the project, jenkins stopped building the project. The error text is as follows.

```
Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :data
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :data
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :data
```

So, what is the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Run following on your server running jenkins (`Google Repository` artifacts need to be udpated).

```
android update sdk --no-ui
```